# com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][10120][11936][4.14.88] Invalid operation: Lob is closed. ERRORCODE=-4470, SQLSTATE=null

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, clob

In our application we are having a simple *POJO* class that has a *Clob* attribute within it.

I am having issue in getting the String representation of that *Clob* entity.

Say I have already queried and cached the result in the *POJO* object, now I am trying to get the String value of the Clob as below.

```
int aLength = (int)myPojo.getClobField().length();
String aStringValue = myPojo.getClobField().getSubString(1L, aLength);
```

But the above execution gives me the error,

***com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][10120][11936][4.14.88] Invalid operation: Lob is closed. ERRORCODE=-4470, SQLSTATE=null***

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Clob` Java object is not a copy of the `CLOB` value stored in the database. It is a locator (pointer), which becomes invalid after the result set is closed. You'll need to copy `CLOB` contents while processing the result set.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So the better option would be to have a String field in my POJO which I'll initialize using the `getSubString()` of the `Clob`. Is it?

Comment: I don't know what is best for you because I don't know your requirements.

Answer (score 3):

This issue can be solved by adding `progressiveStreaming=2;` argument to the connection url

The fully specified Connection URL is to be given as below:

```
jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/SAMPLE:progressiveStreaming=2;
```

In case you have exception on that parameter add the following to it or add any one or combinations of these parameters to fix it:

```
jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/SAMPLE:driverType=4;fullyMaterializeLobData=true;fullyMaterializeInputStreams=true;progressiveStreaming=2;progresssiveLocators=2;
```

It is preferred to use `db2jcc4.jar`

Comment: Is it `progresssiveLocators` or `progressiveLocators`  - even found both on ibm sites...

Answer (score 0):

For hibernate users ,   when mapping to a database Lob type (BLOB or CLOB) the field should be annotated @Lob and no need to keep the copy  , you can directely convert it in to character array  like

```
(java.sql.Clob)payload.field1 bodyText = clobTest.getCharacterStream() 
 targetString = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(bodyText) 
int length=targetString.length();
payload.PAYLOADHEADERS=targetString
return payload
```

Make sure you have added progressiveStreaming=2;  in your data-source configuration properties.